# Hot spot analysis widget application programmed in JavaScript API is having trouble connecting to my portal

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal

```
            //Define the default inputs for the Hot Spot widget
        var hotSpotParams = {
            id: "analysisTool",
            analysisLayer: sex_offenders,
            portalUrl: "http://utdepps.maps.arcgis.com/home/organization.html",
            aggregationPolygonLayers: [sex_offenders],
            boundingPolygonLayers: [sex_offenders],
            showHelp: false,
            showSelectAnalysisLayer: false,
            showCredits: false,
            map: map,
            returnFeatureCollection: true
        };

        var hotSpots = new FindHotSpots(hotSpotParams, "hotSpotDiv");
        hotSpots.startup();

        //If any errors occur reset the widget (Not Working...troubleshoot)
        on(hotSpots, "job-fail", function(params){
            resetTool("error");
        });
        on(hotSpots, "job-status", function(status){
          if(status.jobStatus === 'esriJobFailed'){
          alert("Job Failed: " + status.messages[0].description);
            resetTool("error");
          }

        });
        on(hotSpots, "job-cancel", function(){
            resetTool("error");
        });
        on(hotSpots, "job-submit", function(result){
            //display the loading icon
            domUtils.show(dom.byId("loader"));
            resetTool("submit");

        });
        //The hot spots analysis has finished successfully - display the results
        on(hotSpots, "job-result", function(result){

            //hide the loading icon
            domUtils.hide(dom.byId("loader"));

            //add the results to the map and display the legend.
            if(result.value){
                var template = new InfoTemplate("Results", "${*}");
                var resultLayer = new FeatureLayer(result.value.url || result.value, {
                    infoTemplate: template,
                    outFields: ["*"],
                    opacity: 0.7, //default too transparent
                    id: "resultLayer"
                });

                map.addLayer(resultLayer);
                //refresh and display the legend
                domUtils.show(dom.byId("legendContainer"));
                legend.refresh([{layer: resultLayer}]);
            }
            if(result.analysisReport){
                //hide the hot spots panel and show the analysis info.
                domUtils.hide(dom.byId("toolPanel"));
                domUtils.show(dom.byId("infoPanel"));
                dom.byId("analysisInfo").innerHTML = result.analysisReport;
            }

            //re-enable the hot spots tool
            hotSpots.set("disableRunAnalysis", false);

        });
    }

    function resetTool(status){
        if(status === "error"){
            var tool = registry.byId("analysisTool");
            tool.set("disableRunAnalysis", false);
        }
        //Analysis started lets clean up any old results
        //Hide the legend, remove the results layer
        var layer = map.getLayer("resultLayer");
        if(layer){
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        }
        domUtils.hide(dom.byId("legendContainer"));
    }
    function showToolPanel(){
      //expand the right panel to display the content
        var cp = registry.byId("rightPanel");
        domStyle.set(cp.domNode, {width: "20%"});
        registry.byId("mainWin").resize();

        map.reposition();
        map.resize();
    }
  });
});
```

I'm trying to use JavaScript API to program a widget to give generate a hot spot analysis of sex offenders. My program seems to be having trouble connecting to arcgis.com (if I use https://www.arcgis.com, it prompts for a login screen. No credentials will work). I can load the feature classes, but I can't seem to get the analysis function to work.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using Portal for ArcGIS so I've added a tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your hotSpotParams object, try setting `portalUrl` to `https://utdepps.maps.arcgis.com`.